# URI mismatch error 400 .NET, my code always points to a different URL

Tags: c#, .net, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client, redirect-uri-mismatch

At this point every information is welcomed. I'm trying to connect via OAuth2 to a Google Drive API, but when I run my credentials:

```
credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                        GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                        Scopes,
                        "user",
                        CancellationToken.None,
                        new FileDataStore("TokenStore"),
                        new LocalServerCodeReceiver(RedirectUri)).Result;
}
```

I always get this error:

[redirect_uri](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHcCu.png)

The problem I have is that the url changes every time I call that part of code, so it is impossible to enter in the GoogleCloud Console a redirect url that matches. I have tried everything, setting the ports statically from VS, registering different authentication urls, I have checked my client id and the client secret and matches perfectly, at this point I don't really know where to go, since I haven't been able to set that url statically in any way.

Anny suggestions?

This is the full code:

```
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Flows;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses;
using Google.Apis.Drive.v3;
using Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DriveQuickstart
{
    public class Program
    {
        // If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
        // at ~/.credentials/drive-dotnet-quickstart.json
        //follow this link
        //https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/dotnet

        static string[] Scopes = { DriveService.Scope.DriveReadonly };
        static string ApplicationName = "Drive API .NET Quickstart";

        public static void Drive()
        {
            try
            {
                UserCredential credential;

                const string RedirectUri = "http://localhost:61930/authorize/";

                using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                        GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                        Scopes,
                        "user",
                        CancellationToken.None,
                        new FileDataStore("TokenStore"),
                        new LocalServerCodeReceiver(RedirectUri)).Result;
                }

                // Create Drive API service.
                var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                    ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
                });

                // Define parameters of request.
                FilesResource.ListRequest listRequest = service.Files.List();
                listRequest.PageSize = 10;
                listRequest.Fields = "nextPageToken, files(id, name)";

                // List files.
                IList<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File> files = listRequest.Execute()
                     .Files;
                Console.WriteLine("Files:");

                if (files != null && files.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (var file in files)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", file.Name, file.Id);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("No files found.");
                }

                Console.Read();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw e;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried everything, clearly the problem is that a url is generated dynamically and I cannot make it static, I don't know if it is my part of the code or it could be something in the project at a global level, but I have set the ports in a way static from the `appsettings.json` or `web.config` etc and nothing, at the point of validating credentials it redirects to another port, thanks everyone!

Comment: Please do not include images of errors unless there is no way to show it as text (ideally in English). Also it does not look like the question has anything to do with Visual Studio - I removed that tag, if indeed you are writing and extension to VS (or other suitable cases as outlined in tag's wiki) please [edit] it into the question.

Comment: I had in mind that maybe it was some issue related to the configuration of the Visual Studio.

Comment: You need to fix your ide so that its not adding random ports.  [How to fix redirect uri missmatch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QHz1Rs6lZHQ) Tip: Are you aware that the code you are using is for an installed application and not a web app?

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo And how do I control through my ide? I am using VS, I have tried to statically assign the ports from the startup, the only thing I have managed to do is modify the ports on which I initially launch the app, but when I authenticate with Google, it randomly generates that url for me.. thx

Comment: Why do you have a web.config in an installed app?

Comment: My mistake, I don't have a web.config, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is mainly that you have code for an installed / desktop application yet you are using client_secret.json for a web application which is wrong.   Go create the correct credential type.

If you really want to use web creds for some reason which I dont understand you can fix the redirect uri error by going to google developer console and add the redirect uri exactly as it is written here

[image]

[How to fix redirect URI missmatch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QHz1Rs6lZHQ)

Comment: The issue is that the port is random and changes every time.

Comment: Then fix your ide so that it uses a static port